# How can I collect webform data from 500 Drupal sites as entities in a centrally managed Drupal site?

Tags: commerce, feeds, services, 8

The scenario is as follows:

I have 500 products, each has its own webpage and domain on an Aegir (BOA) server.
I want to collect data that customers submit.

To start with a simple example: the customers need to be able to submit data in a contact form. I need that data to show up in the central drupal site in a view.

A more advanced setup would be to allow customers to buy the product promoted on the website, while their orders are collected in a centralized drupal Commerce site.

I see a number of modules that might be helpful, like Feeds, Services, RESTful etc. but I haven't found any practical examples related to my setup.

What modules or methods are good for this scenario, without custom coding?

Comment: Create views of webform submissions rendered as RSS feed, then use the Feeds module to fetch these feeds and turn the submissions into content in your central instance. There, another view would show all retrieved content.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I have to create 500 feed importers? I think that one option would be to use one email box to collect all webform submissions from all websites, and use one feed importer on the central instance can import those emails as entities. But I think the drawback of using feeds is that a response to/interaction with the submitting customer is not instantaneous.